# optimize cursor query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

We have a database with more the 10,000,000 records. The following statements is used to replace some of the words in each record with a different word from another table, but because there are so many records the execution doesn't even finish in a full day, is there anyway it can be optimized?

```
DECLARE My_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT
        full_santance
    ,   id
    FROM
        dbo.combined
    WHERE
        id BETWEEN 9000000 AND 10000000

DECLARE My_Cursor_r CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT
        old
    ,   new
    FROM
        dbo.changesTable

DECLARE @full_santance varchar(500)
DECLARE @id numeric(18, 0)
DECLARE @word_old varchar(500)
DECLARE @word_new varchar(500)
DECLARE @corrected varchar(500)
DECLARE @r_word varchar(500)

OPEN My_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @full_santance, @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
            SET @corrected = @full_santance

            OPEN My_Cursor_r
            FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor_r INTO @word_old, @word_new
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                  BEGIN
                        IF @corrected LIKE '%[^a-z]' + REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_old),'_', '') + '[^a-z]%'
                           OR @corrected LIKE '%[^a-z]' + REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_old), '_', '') 
                           OR @corrected LIKE REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_old), '_','') + '[^a-z]%'
                           OR @corrected LIKE REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_old), '_','')
                           BEGIN
                                 SET @corrected = REPLACE(@corrected,REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_old),'_', ' '),REPLACE(RTRIM(@word_new),'_', ' '))
                           END

                        FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor_r INTO @word_old, @word_new
                  END

            CLOSE My_Cursor_r

            IF @corrected <> @full_santance
               BEGIN
                     UPDATE
                        dbo.combined
                     SET
                        full_santance = @corrected
                     WHERE
                        id = @id
               END

            FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @word, @id
      END
CLOSE My_Cursor
DEALLOCATE My_Cursor
DEALLOCATE My_Cursor_r
```

Comment: show small sample data of both table and which table column need to be updated by which one and both table relation.

Comment: My guess is the inner cursor might be as easy to just rewrite without a cursor. Also - is this something that runs regularly or is it a one-shot update? Because if it is one shot, I'd properly look towards trying to do it in another table/database and then updating all rows at once. (10.000.000 records might sound like a lot, but it shouldn't really be). And if it runs often, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @combined TABLE (id int, full_santance varchar(max))
INSERT @combined VALUES
(1, 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'),
(2, 'the dog days of summer')

DECLARE @changesTable TABLE (old varchar(max), new varchar(max) )
INSERT @changesTable VALUES
('dog','cat'),
('the','a')

SELECT
  id,
  LTRIM((
    SELECT ' '+ISNULL(new,word)
    FROM @combined c2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(full_santance,' ','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS xml) xml1 ) t1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT n.value('.','varchar(max)') AS word FROM xml1.nodes('a') x(n) ) t2
    LEFT JOIN @changesTable ON word = old
    WHERE c1.id = c2.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ))
FROM @combined c1
```